# Disable TLS on SQL-Connection in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, connection-string

I'm `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` for dealing with MS SQL-Server connections.
Now, for debug reasons I need to temporarily disable TLS encryption of the `SqlConnection` so I can monitor it with wireshark.

Setting "encrypt=false" in connection string had no effect. Since the SQL Server instance isn't in my field of responsibility I cannot modify anything there.

Is there a way to disable connection security?

Comment: What do you want to monitor using wire shark?

Comment: If SQL server is set to require secure/encrypted connections, then no, you can't disable that at client side. Otherwise I ask same question as @ChetanRanpariya - I have coded against SQL server for many long years and I have yet to see a case, when using SQL native tools cannot gather enough information. Of course there are cases, when firewall or something disables SQL connection entirely - but seems that you can connect to SQL.

Comment: Do you have sufficient access to the instance to monitor the requests via SQL Profiler?

Comment: I need to see which actual SQL Code an application sends to the SQL Server for debugging. SQL Profiler seems to be a subject, I'll investigate

Comment: Problem is/was, that I need the ALTER_TRACE permission on SQL Server to use the corresponding feature in the profiler. So there seemed no feasible way to acheive this kind of debugging on that server and I had to use a manual DB-Server setup.